# Searching files by multiple search patterns in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, script

I got this piped command:

```
Get-Childitem -Path E:\Shares\ -Recurse -Filter *Synformulas* | Export-csv -Path E:\result.csv
```

Now it is like that, that I need to search for multiple search terms. I cannot append simply them to the -Filter flag.

Can anybody tell me how can search through a folder recursively for file names with multiple search terms?

Answer (score 5):

The **-Filter** parameter only accepts a single string.
However, the **-Include** parameter accepts multiple values,
but qualifies the **-Path** argument.

The idea is to append `\*` to the end of the path, and then use
**-Include** to select multiple wildcard strings.
Note that quoting strings is unnecessary in arguments unless they
contain spaces or special characters.

Example:

```
Get-Childitem -Path E:\Shares\* -Recurse -Include *Synformulas*, *otherformula* | Export-csv -Path E:\result.csv
```

Comment: harrymc deserves extra points for this. I had been trying the MS doco examples with no luck and not understanding that ending `-Path` with wildcard was the key.

Answer (score 1):

One way is probably just to filter the files as a step in your pipeline:

```
Get-Childitem -Path E:\Shares\ -Recurse | 
  Where-Object { $_.Name -Like "*Foo*" -or $_.Name -Like "*Bar*" } |
  Export-csv -Path E:\result.csv
```

This also lets you use `-Match` for regex filtering if you prefer:

```
... | Where-Object {$_.Name -match 'Foo|Bar'} | ...
```